# $\theta=\int_{0}^{2}3e^{-3x}dx$ Compute theta using Monte-Carlo Method

Tags: statistics, monte-carlo

$\theta=\int_{0}^{2}3e^{-3x}dx$

Using Monte-Carlo method estimate the confidence intervals for the integral above. Use a distribution different from the uniform distribution to minimize the confidence intervals.

I tried using variable substitute so $\theta=\int_{0}^{1}6e^{-6t}dt$ and using the beta distribution(1,6) the plots seem to agree but the estimate for $\theta$ seems to be way to big, here is the R output:

```
> integral2<-function(n) {
+   x<-runif(n)
+   fy<-dbeta(x,1,6)
+   g_y<-6*exp(1)^(-6*x)
+   hy<-(g_y/fy)
+   sdg_y<-sd(g_y)
+   theta<-mean(hy)
+   sdtheta<-sqrt(sum((hy-theta)^2)/(n-1))
+   print(max(hy))
+   print(theta)
+   print(sqrt(sum((hy-theta)^2)/(n-1)))
+ 
+   return(c(theta-sdtheta*qnorm(0.975)/sqrt(n),theta+sdtheta*qnorm(0.975)/sqrt(n)))
+ }
> integral2(10000)
[1] 1.484229e+17 #max(hy)
[1] 2.123842e+13 #theta
[1] 1.608726e+15 #sdtheta
[1] -1.029203e+13  5.276887e+13 #confidence interval for theta
```

Comment: It depends a bit on what you're allowed to use, I think. For instance, this is actually just the probability that an exponential random variable with rate $3$ is in $[0,2]$. So you can just sample exponential variables and count directly. (If you can't directly sample exponential variables, you can always take the logarithm of a uniform variable instead.) But if you can't use that fact, then we'd need to know what you *can* use.

Comment: The problem here is that the support of an exponential variable is $(0,\infty)$ so I don't see how I could use that...

Comment: For each sample $X$, if it's in $[0,2]$, count that as $1$, otherwise count it as $0$. In many cases this is a high variance procedure and therefore not a good idea, but in this case the variance is quite small because the probability of falling in $[0,2]$ is quite large.

Comment: In particular, the exact answer is $1-e^{-6}$ which is $0.9975$ to 4 digits; with 1000 samples I got 998 in the interval for an estimate of $0.998$ on the first try. Of course as with anything with MC this is random, so subsequent trials give $0.996$, $0.997$, etc., but this is pretty good. In particular you should expect an error of about $\frac{0.01}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Is @Ian correct that you intend $\theta$ to be the success probability of a binomial random variable? Your code seems to suggest that. If, so, what $n$ do you have in mind?